# Reactjs Wizard Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There are multiple cards present on the page. On click of every card, I want to navigate it to the wizard form from where the user has left before. How it can be done?

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: i am having a wizard in Reactjs. In wizard, there are multiple forms available. I am making some changes in wizard and closing it. On click of close, i have designed different cards which contains diffrent information which I have filled in the wizard. What i want is, on click of those cards, i should be able to open the form in the wizard, where the user has left before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find a way to persist the state of closed card for that user.

1. You can use localStorage to persist the card state when card is closed and not complete
2. Cache card state in the backend and retrieve it on card mount.

In both cases, you need to decide when to invalidate the cached data.

Hope it helps

Comment: local storage helps